# Calling arrays within an array php

Tags: php, arrays, button, module

I am creating an e Learning module that uses arrays to go through the module.  I need to add icons at the bottom of all the different chapters within the section.

example: page 1 will have 2 links on the bottom: page 2 & page 3.

code:

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <?php
  
  include 'buttons_array.php';
  
  $page = ($_GET['page']);
  
 ?>
 <head>
        <div class="buttons">
        <?php
     foreach(array_unique($buttons) as $index=>$section) {
     echo "<tr><td><a href=./" . $filename . ".php?page=" . ($index +1). ">" . $section . "</a></td></tr>";
     }
  ?>
        </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

buttons_array.php

```html
<?php

$buttons = array(

   //page 1
   "page 1 Title",
   
   //page 2
   "Page 2 Title",
   
   //page 3
   "Page 3 Title",
   
   //page 4
    "Page 4 Title"
    
    );
 
$links = array(
   
   //page 1
   "$buttons page 2, $buttons page 3",
   
   //page 2
   "$buttons page1, $buttons page 3",
   
   //page 3
   "$buttons page1, $buttons page 2"
   

)      
 ?>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: "I can't figure out how to call only certain variables within the arrays." - and we can't figure out what the question is. "calling variables" and "calling arrays" doesn't make any sense. "certain" is vague.. what's the criteria? also, no example or expected output is shown

Answer (score 0):

You can access the arrays by their keys.

In the case of your example `$buttons[0], $buttons[1], $buttons[2], $buttons[3]`

The same would go for $links - `$links[0], $links[1], $links[2], $links[3]`

In the case of wanting to grab the pair, simply create a integer that you use in replacement of the direct value.

```
    $indexId = 0;

    $buttons[$indexId];
    $links[$indexId];
```

Remember in PHP arrays are zero based, meaning they start their key counter at 0.

You can access the PHP manuals help on arrays here [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, but I'm still a little confused.  

If page 1 needs to have 2 buttons on the bottom(page 2 & 3) and then on page 2 will have 2 buttons on the bottom(page 1 & 3) how would I assign them to each page, and then call them on the index page?

Comment: I would assign indexes to them and call them as you need.  What I mean by this is group them toghther, just like my example, then - when you are on a page - replace my example - $indexId with $pageId - and you should retrieve the content you need.    It's hard to say without the full context of what you're doing.  Hope this helps!